# Load website from SD card

Tags: esp8266, spi, sd-card, web-server

I combined two different codes together, a captive portal and a SD card web server. I encountered a problem which the website in the SD card doesn't load when I connect to the AP (captive portal page). Here's the code..

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "./DNSServer.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

const byte        DNS_PORT = 53;          // Capture DNS requests on port 53
IPAddress         apIP(10, 10, 10, 1);    // Private network for server
DNSServer         dnsServer;              // Create the DNS object
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
String responseHTML = ""
                      "<html><head><title>Captive Portal Test</title>"
                      "<style>html,body{margin:0;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}"
                      "img{ min-height:100%; min-width:100%;height:auto;width:auto;"
                      "position:absolute;top:-100%; bottom:-100%;left:-100%; right:-100%;"
                      "margin:auto;}</style></head><body><img src='test.png' /><h1>TEST</h1></body></html>";


static bool hasSD = false;
File uploadFile;

void returnOK() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "");
}

void returnFail(String msg) {
  server.send(500, "text/plain", msg + "\r\n");
}

bool loadFromSdCard(String path) {
  String dataType = "text/plain";
  if (path.endsWith("/")) path += "index.htm";
  if (path.endsWith(".src")) path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));
  else if (path.endsWith(".htm")) dataType = "text/html";
  else if (path.endsWith(".css")) dataType = "text/css";
  else if (path.endsWith(".js")) dataType = "application/javascript";
  else if (path.endsWith(".png")) dataType = "image/png";
  else if (path.endsWith(".gif")) dataType = "image/gif";
  else if (path.endsWith(".jpg")) dataType = "image/jpeg";
  else if (path.endsWith(".ico")) dataType = "image/x-icon";
  else if (path.endsWith(".xml")) dataType = "text/xml";
  else if (path.endsWith(".pdf")) dataType = "application/pdf";
  else if (path.endsWith(".zip")) dataType = "application/zip";

  File dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  if (dataFile.isDirectory()) {
    path += "/index.htm";
    dataType = "text/html";
    dataFile = SD.open(path.c_str());
  }

  if (!dataFile)
    return false;

  if (server.hasArg("download")) dataType = "application/octet-stream";

  if (server.streamFile(dataFile, dataType) != dataFile.size()) {
  }

  dataFile.close();
  return true;
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (hasSD && loadFromSdCard(server.uri())) return;
  String message = "SDCARD Not Detected\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " NAME:" + server.argName(i) + "\n VALUE:" + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup(void) {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));
  WiFi.softAP("TEST AP");
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);
  //PROBLEM HERE/
  server.onNotFound([]() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", responseHTML);
  });

  server.begin();

  if (SD.begin(SS)) {
    hasSD = true;
  }
}

void loop(void) {
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  server.handleClient();
}
```

This code replies the `responseHTML` as a Captive portal page which immediately pop-ups when I connect to the AP:

```cpp
server.onNotFound([]() {
      server.send(200, "text/html", responseHTML);
      });
```

The `void handleNotFound()` handles the page/file request from the browser but if I use it on

```cpp
server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
```

The captive portal won't show but if I type the server address `10.10.10.1`, the page will appear. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `hasSD &&` from `void handleNotFound()` function.

It worked for me.